# Does Electron's main thread block BrowserWindow?

Tags: electron, single-threaded

I'm building an application that runs an Electron application. What I'm seeing is that when the main thread gets busy running its own operations, BrowserWindow's thread will get blocked (just like it does if the BrowserWindow itself is running javascript).

Are these sharing the same thread? If so, what is the best way to separate them?

Comment: I think I can infer what you mean, but can you expand on "influence BrowserWindow just like it does in web applications". A BrowserWindow should create another Renderer process. The communication between that Renderer and Main will of course use the same thread, and some other operations need to be done in the main process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, it's not really Electron's main thread. It'd be more accurate to say that it's Node's thread.

Second, the Main process' main thread is used (among other things of course) to communicate between the Main process and the Renderer process that's used by the `BrowserWindow`, so if your main thread is performing a large synchronous operation, your main thread will block, and that could certainly affect the responsiveness of your window.

> what is the best way to separate them?

I can't really provide a general solution that will be useful in all cases. You should present a specific example. What is your main thread busy doing?

You can look into using WebWorkers. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36942555/does-the-electron-framework-allow-multi-threading-through-web-workers).

Comment: great reference thank you, would you say something like napa also work in this case?

Comment: @user2167582 What is napa?

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/napajs, it is like a wrapper for child processes. But from your comments, I speculate that anything in this nature can work?

Comment: You could use [Node worker threads](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html). Electron-related gotchas [thread](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/18540#issuecomment-647733788).

Answer (score 1):

In short, yes, Electron’s main thread can (somewhat counter-intuitively) “block” renderer UI.

Apparently[0], Electron relies on ongoing main-renderer communication a lot in background, and that is in addition to explicit IPC calls you make. Thus, if main thread is locking on some operations, UI will lag like crazy *even if your own IPC calls are not blocked*.

Ways around this:

- You could use [Node worker threads](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html)[1] in main.
- You could use Web Workers, with or without spinning “hidden renderers”.

#### See also

- [0] [The Horror of Blocking Electron’s Main Process](https://medium.com/actualbudget/the-horror-of-blocking-electrons-main-process-351bf11a763c)
- [1] Gotchas on using Node worker threads in Electron: [thread in #18540](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/18540#issuecomment-647733788)